# Error running Deep-shopping model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to reproduce results of [Deep-shopping model](https://github.com/wenxinxu/deep-shopping), but when I run the `train_n_test.py` file, I get the following error:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-754aa36f8c5c> in <module>()
      8 import time
      9 from datetime import datetime
---> 10 from simple_resnet import *
     11 from hyper_parameters import *
     12 

~/deep-shopping/simple_resnet.py in <module>()
      6 '''
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 from hyper_parameters import *
      9 
     10 #import tensorflow as tf

~/deep-shopping/hyper_parameters.py in <module>()
     31 
     32 ## Hyper-parameters about the model
---> 33 tf.app.flags.DEFINE_int('num_residual_blocks', 5, '''number of residual blocks in ResNet''')
     34 
     35 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.platform.flags' has no attribute 'DEFINE_int'
```

I find this error for both python2.7 and python3.5

My question:

How to solve this bug ?

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using? Try `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` from the command line.

Comment: @Engineero: tensforflow 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `simple_resnet.py` file is missing. The authors have not provided that code file in the repository. Try to create it using `resnet.py` [from this link](https://github.com/wenxinxu/resnet-in-tensorflow/blob/master/resnet.py).

Comment: Were you able to run it?